# Not getting all nearby places react native project

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I want to show all hotel in Google Maps with react native, but its not showing all places, I show many places but some don't. How can I fix this. I am trying everythink but its not fix
its my code for hotel.

```
const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=1000&type=lodging&key=${API_KEY}`)
  this.setState({
            places: results,
    fetching:false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API - Nearby Search can return as many as 60 results, divided into three pages with 20 results each. If your search query is more than 20 results, the response will include the `next_page_token` value which you can pass to the `pagetoken` parameter of the new search request to get the next sets of results for that search query.

But, if there is no `next_page_token` it means that there are no further results.

Here is a sample request with a `next_page_token` property: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&type=food&key=YOUR_API_KEY

For your reference, you may check the Places Nearby Search documentation on [how to access additional results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging).

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, i know this. but i dont know how can i do, i didnt find example.